# How telegram bot can get file_id of uploaded file?

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

In telegram API documentation I see: "You can either pass a **file_id** as String to resend a photo that is already on the Telegram servers", but I can't find ways to get file_id of uploaded file. How can I get it?

Answer (score 11):

Its depended to your content_types ,for example:

Video:

```
message.video.file_id
```

Audio:

```
message.audio.file_id
```

Photo:

```
message.photo[2].file_id
```

For more see [this](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI#types) link.

Answer (score 6):

This is the easiest way I've found to do it.

Upload your file to any chat and forward the message to @RawDataBot. It will return something like this:

```
{
    "update_id": 754677603,
    "message": {
        "message_id": 403656,
        "from": {
            "id": xxx,
            "is_bot": false,
            "first_name": "xxx",
            "username": "xxx",
            "language_code": "en"
        },
        "chat": {
            "id": xxx,
            "first_name": "xxx",
            "username": "xxx",
            "type": "private"
        },
        "date": 1589342513,
        "forward_from": {
            "id": xxx,
            "is_bot": false,
            "first_name": "xxx",
            "username": "xxx",
            "language_code": "en"
        },
        "forward_date": 1589342184,
        "document": {
            "file_name": "filename.pdf",
            "mime_type": "application/pdf",
            "file_id": "This_Is_The_Thing_You_Need",
            "file_unique_id": "notthis",
            "file_size": 123605
        }
    }
}
```

What you need is the string under `file_id`. Once you have copied that, you can simply the following code to send the message.

```
    context.bot.sendDocument(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, 
        document = "Your_FILE_ID_HERE")
```

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the method (File type) which you chose to send a file, after sending a file to Telegram a response is returned. For example if you send a MP3 file to Telegram using `sendAudio` method, Telegram returns an `Audio` object which contains the file ID.
Source: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#audio

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answers above, you can log Updates that comes to your bot, Either from `https://api.telegram.org/bot'.BOT_TOKEN.'/getUpdates` or throw updates that come in your application. there you will find a `Json` property like below:

```
{
    "update_id" = 1111111,
    "message" =
        {
            "message_id" = 1111111,
            "from" =
                {
                    "id" = 111111,
                    ...
                }
            "chat" =
                {
                "id" = 111111,
                ...
                }
            "date" = 111111,
            "photo" = 
                {
                    {
                        "file_id" = HERE IS YOU FILE ID 1,
                        "file_size" => XXXX,
                        "width" => XX,
                        "height" => XX,
                    }
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Say you receive a `Message` with an array of `PhotoSize`

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#photosize

As you can see, there's a `file_id`, you can use this to send a photo through `sendPhoto`.

If we assume `Update` is an object, with in it a `Message` object, which in turn provides a `Chat` object with in it a `id` of the chat where the initial message came from and an array of `PhotoSize` (excuse me for using PHP here, but that's my main language...)

`$update->message->photo` is how you can access the array. 
Use some kind of For loop to iterate over the items, or just access the first one if the array isn't bigger than 1.

After that, you can use the result(s) to extract the `file_id` and send it as a `string` via `sendPhoto`'s `photo` parameter and the Chat ID via the `chat_id` parameter.

I hope this helped!

P.S. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpYA6.jpg) is a diagram of my current implementation of the API, i hope it brings some clarity to you!

Answer (score 1):

if you use PHP:

you can write this line for full size:

`$file_id = $updates['message']['photo'][1]['file_id'];`

and this line for thumb:

`$file_id = $updates['message']['photo'][0]['file_id'];`

Answer (score 1):

According to the latest docs (v20.0a6) plenty of classes have been changed. I have found that the easiest way to get started with files is using the effective_attachment property.

```
async def handle_file(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:

    media_item = await context.bot.get_file(update.message.effective_attachment[0].file_id)

    media_url = media_item.file_path
```

For declaring the handler there have also been changes to filters, here is a simple way to declare it:

```
application.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.ATTACHMENT, handle_file))
```