# How to get File_ID of an Image Generated by Bot?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf, telegram-webhook

I'm currently generating an image buffer and sending it to a group using

```
ctx.replyWithPhoto({ source: myBuffer, filename: "image.png" });
```

I'm wanting to reuse this photo to send later and I figured I could use Telegrams `file_id`
for this, but I can't find a way to actually get it. Every example I find is about somone sending a photo to the bot, not the bot creating and sending the photo to the chat.

Any help or ideas on how to do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37225484/11652703).

message: {
message_id: 68,
from: [Object],
chat: [Object],
date: 1625421075,
photo: [Array]
}

From the message object you can access the photo property and you can find the file_id like `message.photo[0].file_id`